# Recuperar un valor de una select con php

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo una lista desplegable en Html que muestra los datos de un campo de la base de datos y lo que quiero cuando el usuario seleccione un valor de la lista desplegable capturar ese valor para luego rellenar los Imput con los datos correspondientes al valor que a seleccionado en la lista desplegable.

Voy  intentar explicarme mejor, yo lo que tengo ahora mismo en el código que he pasado es una lista desplegable que me muestra que me recupera unos códigos de la BBDD, pero lo que quiero es saber que código se a seleccionado en la lista para luego completar de forma automática los siguientes campos en función del código seleccionado.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

```html
<?php
 
//* configuracion database.
include("conexion.php");
 
function filtrado($datos){
    $datos = trim($datos); // Elimina espacios antes y después de los datos
    $datos = stripslashes($datos); // Elimina backslashes \
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos); // Traduce caracteres especiales en entidades HTML
    return $datos;
}
 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
 
// aqui controlar si la query dio error o no.
 
 
?>
 
 
 
 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 
<head>
    <link href="CSS\style_Modificar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="CSS\Modificar_Datos_Principales.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 
 
    <title>Modificar Datos Principales</title>
</head>
 
<body>
 
 
  <h1>MODIFICAR DATOS PRINCIPALES</h1>
 
 
 
 
<div class="Contenido">
 
<form >
 
 
 
 
 
 
<?php
  include("conexion.php");
 
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal';
 
  $result = $conexion->query($query);
 
?>
  <p>Código Interno</p>
  <select multiple name= "cod_interno[]">
       <option value="0" > Seleccione:</option>
    <?php
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
    {
        ?>
 
 
       <option > <?php echo $row['Cod_Interno']; ?></option>
 
 
        <?php
    }
    ?>
  </select>
<?php
 
?> <br>
 
 
 
 
 
 
  Nombre Centro Oficial
  <input type="textbox" name="NombreCentroOficial"><br>
 
  Grupo Hospital
  <input type="textbox" name="GrupoHospital"><br>
 
  Tipo Local
  <input type="textbox" name="TipoLocal"><br>
 
  Territorio QS
  <input type="textbox" name="TerritorioQS"><br>
 
  Código Nacional
  <input type="textbox" name="CodigoOficial"><br>
 
  Código Ofical Autonómico
  <input type="textbox" name="CodigoOficialAutonomico"><br>
 
  Siglas
  <input type="textbox" name="Siglas"><br>
 
  Fecha Alta
  <input type="textbox" name="FechaAlta"><br>
 
  Fecha Baja
  <input type="textbox" name="FechaBaja"><br>
 
  Tipo Baja
  <input type="textbox" name="TipoBaja"><br>
 
  Código Episodio
  <input type="textbox" name="CodigoEpisodio"><br>
 
</form>
 
 
 
 
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Pero al parecer se trataría de mostrar datos de la misma tabla ¿? Si es así, y si no son demasiados datos o demasiadas filas una opción interesante sería cargar toda la información de una vez (usando atributos `data-*`)  y luego mostrarlos cuando sea preciso. Eso evitará dos viajes de ida y vuelta al servidor y lanzar dos consultas a la base de datos para obtener al fin y al cabo los mismos datos.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como planteas el problema, tienes que realizar dos viajes al servidor. Uno se realizaría para rellenar el select, y otro para traer de vuelta los datos del servidor una vez elegida la opción del select.

El primero de los viajes se realizaría mediante la query de php, y el segundo mediante **ajax** para traer los datos y rellenar los huecos.

A cada input le tienes que asignar un id para poder utilizar Javascript o jQuery para identificarlos. En este ejemplo lo haré con jQuery. Ten claro que este código no es copiar y pegar, **tendrás que adaptarlo a tus necesidades**.

En la página dónde tienes el select tendrías que ejecutar un script parecido a:

```
$('#ElIdDeTuSelect').on('change', function() {
  function sendRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url para extraer los datos (p.e extraerDatos.php&id=50)',
            success: function (data) {
                //Deberás tratar el data para colocarlo en cada hueco.
                $('#elIdDelInput').html(parte1delosdatos);
                $('#elIdDeOtroInput').html(parte2delosdatos);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

y en extraerDatos.php&id=x , donde x es el id obtenido del select, tienes que extraer el Id con la variable $_GET["id"] y realizar una query en la que pides todos los datos de la tabla que contiene ese Id, y luego puedes hacer un ECHO con el formato que quieras, o utilizar JSON.

Espero que esto te haya ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo. voy  intentar explicarme mejor, yo lo que tengo ahora mismo en el código que he pasado es una lista desplegable que me muestra que me recupera unos códigos de la BBDD, pero lo que quiero es saber que código se a seleccionado en la lista para luego completar de forma automática los siguientes campos en función del código seleccionado.

Comment: Osea que lo que quieres es rellenar el resto de campos con los valores seleccionados. Eso se haría con Javascript y ajax. Dame unos minutos para poder editar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo. Voy a intentar hacelo aunque yo de ajax no se nada xd. pero gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Lo estoy intentando pero no doy con ello, lo podría hacer la modificación sobre mi código para ver como queda y poder entenderlo para futuras ocasiones. un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Dos cosas: **1º.-** Eso de *"A cada input le tienes que asignar un id para poder utilizar Javascript"* no es cierto, puedes seleccionar el elemento mediante multitud de combinaciones ([selectores jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).  **2º.-**  Es "peligroso" aconsejar el uso de un selector tan genérico como el que indicas `$('select').on('change', function() {...`  pues si hay otros selectores en la página también lanzarán la petición ajax.

Comment: Obviamente no es un código exacto. Tiene que adaptarlo a sus circunstancias. ese $('select') debería ser $('#miselect' )

Comment: Pues indícalo que no cuesta ;)  piensa que gente inexperta usará las repuestas como base para sus correcciones o aprendizaje, se trata de ayudar al OP y de paso dejar una base de referencias sólidas para futuras cuestiones similares, por eso se hace énfasis en realizar respuestas de calidad, no una mera repuesta rápida a un problema puntual.